# False positives probability and Bayes Theorem formulation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

### Problem

Assume a predictive model can tell from a user's Twitter posts whether the user is a male or a female.

- 20% of the users are females.
- If a person is a female, the model is 90% inclined to answer correctly.
- If a person is a male, the model is 70% inclined to answer correctly.

Assume the model describes the user being a female. What is the probability that the user is actually a male?

### Attempt

Applying Bayes' Theorem, I created the tree and from this formulated the following equation.

$$ P(male | wrong) = \frac{P(male)P(wrong | male)}{P(wrong)} $$
$$ ... =\frac{P(male)P(wrong | male)}{P(male)P(wrong|male)+P(female)P(wrong|female)}$$

Plugging into this formula, I get
$$ P(male | wrong) = \frac{0.8 \times 0.3}{0.8 \times 0.3+0.2 \times 0.1}=.93 \implies 93\%$$

### Notes

Is my approach to this problem correct? I assume if it is, then the calculation should be too. Otherwise, any guidance on how to formulate Bayes' theorem in this case will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks fine! Good job.

Comment: What do you take $wrong$ to represent?

Comment: $wrong$ denotes the model answering incorrectly. So, it is $0.1$ if the model selects male when the user is actually a female, and likewise $0.3$ if the model selects female when the user is actually a male.

Comment: The condition is that the model *describes the user as female*, so it is **not** *wrong* when the user is actually female.

Comment: Thus, you need to find $$\mathsf P(\text{is_male}\mid\text{says_female})=\dfrac{\mathsf P(\text{says_female}\cap \text{is_male})}{\mathsf P(\text{says_female}\cap \text{is_male})+\mathsf P(\text{says_female}\cap \text{is_female})}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $ wrong_{f} $ to be the probability that the machine is wrong in saying the individual is female (when he is a male).

$$ P(male | wrong_{f}) = \frac{P(male)P(wrong_{f} | male)}{P(wrong_{f})} $$
$$ ... =\frac{P(male)P(wrong_{f} | male)}{P(male)P(wrong_{f}|male)+P(female)P(wrong_{m}|female)}$$

Plugging in,
$$ P(male | wrong_{f}) = \frac{0.8 \times 0.3}{0.8 \times 0.3+0.2 \times 0.9}=.57 \implies 57\%$$